# Tableau parameter filter with multiple values?

Tags: tableau-api

In Tableau 9.2, I currently have a parameter set up which contains multiple string values and an additional "All" value.  I also have a calculated field which only contains the `Str([some_field])` function.  I have then dragged this calculated field into the "filters" pane and from there enabled "use all" and put the following formula under the "condition" tab:

```
// If All is selected, then do not filter
[my_filter_parameter] = 'All' OR 
// Otherwise, filter on the current parameter
[my_filter_parameter] = [my_calculated_Field]
```

After creating the calculated field for multiple sheets in my dashboard (which use different data sources all contain the common some_field), then I can change the parameter's value and it will filter all of the sheets at once.

My issue is that I need this to take on multiple values at once via a check-box.  I understand that a parameter can only take on one value at a time, so I am wondering how I can do this without making the same filter for each individual sheet in the dashboard.  Perhaps this can be done with a calculated field?

EDIT:  I have tried the technique [here](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/creating-filter-actions-dashboards) to make a global filter via a control view.  This allows me to use Ctrl+Clicking to select multiple values in some_field at once, however I still do not have a dropdown box.  Alternatively, if anyone knows how to use this method with a dropdown box, then that would be another solution.

Comment: Based solely on what you have provided, there is no reason for a parameter. If you are only filtering on what is in the calculated field, you should filter on it directly. There is an option to include the `All` choice.

Comment: Nicarus: This filter is to be applied to all sheets in the dashboard, so I am using a parameter to filter them all at once.  If there is a way to do this without a parameter that doesn't require me to make a filter check box for each individual sheet in the dashboard, then I would be open to it.

Comment: Are the sheets using the same data source? If so, apply the filter to the relevant sheets - or all sheets in the data source.

Comment: Not all of the sheets are the same data source, as per my question.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your situation correctly, I have accomplished this using the following:

Create a calculated field and put the following code:

```
if [parameters].parametername = 'All' then true
elseif [parameters].parametername = FILTEREDCOLUMN then true
else false
end
```

Add that calculated field to the filters pane and select "True" - in other words, filter out any records where the calculated field is False. If the parameter you selected is "All" then all records will be True.  Otherwise, it will only be True if the parameter matches the FILTEREDCOLUMN. I hope that helps.

Comment: The `[parameters].parametername` caused a `malformed field name` for `[parameters]` so I replaced `[parameters].parametername` with `[my_parameter_name]` which seems to work.  Then, it gave me an error in the calculated field: `Cannot use 'boolean' type in 'if' expression.`  I'm using Tableau 9.2

Comment: d'oh - sorry. Need to make the result a string instead of boolean; use this code instead.`if [parameters].parametername = 'All' then 'true'
elseif [parameters].parametername = FILTEREDCOLUMN then 'true'
else 'false'
end`

Comment: That's no longer causing an error, however how can I get this to work with multiple values selected at once via a check-box?

Comment: Hmm... I don't think Tableau currently offers/supports multi-value parameters. https://community.tableau.com/ideas/1313  https://community.tableau.com/message/379026 But, just like we did with the "all" logic, you may be able to add a logic block for a custom entry. Like, if you wanted the user to select "East", you may be able to build logic to filter a field for only the 'east' entries. Like the code below, and then filter to only display 'True'

Comment: `//Filter Logic
if [testparameter] = 'Rx' 
and ([Event Type] = 'Rx Scripts'
or [Event Type] = 'Rx Brand Scripts') then 'True' 


elseif [testparameter] = 'East' 
and ([Event Type] = 'Virginia'
or [Event Type] = 'DC'
or [Event Type] = 'Maryland') then 'True'
else 'False' end ` // Note that these strings are case sensitive, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Parameter can pass only one value at a time ,i.e. Parameter Control will have Single Drop Down List.